# ¿Por qué no puedo ver el contenido de una carpeta en github?

Tags: git, github, git-push, repositorio

Ya revise las repuestas de otro usuario con el mismo caso, pero el problema es que yo no tengo ninguna carpeta oculta llamada .git, en la ubicación de las carpetas anecdotes y unicafe, y no se que puedo hacer para que desde mi repositorio en GitHub me permita ver el contenido de las carpetas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando utilice git remote -v y me salio esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aunque me sale lo mismo con la carpeta que si puedo ver el contenido, les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Tendrias que empujar ramas/revisiones a dicho repositorio? Eso es lo más básico. Ya lo hiciste? Qué pasó al hacer push?

Comment: sistema operativo? son carpetas o accesos directos?

Comment: si realice el push hace dos horas, al intentar realizar de nuevo me dice "Everything up-to-date", mi sistema operativo es Windows, y en efecto son carpetas normales, de forma local puedo acceder a ellas sin ningún problema, pero en el repositorio me salen con ese símbolo y no puedo acceder.

Comment: Probablemente eran submódulos. O bien habías creado dentro de ellas otros repositorios sin querer (usando `git init`). Mira aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/1264820 Quizás el explorador de windows no te mostraba las .git anidadas, pero es sospechoso que sí que tuvieran un `.gitignore` anidado.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionarlo tuve que eliminar el repositorio de Github, elimine de forma local la carpeta oculta .git, después comencé desde cero volviendo a crear el repo en Github, en la consola coloque el comando de git init, después el git remote add origin (link del nuevo repo creado) y listo.
realice todo el proceso normal del commit y el push, al abrir el nuevo repositorio las carpetas estan normales y permiten acceder sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

En el repositorio remoto si no puedes ver contenido es que no has realizado versionamiento de su contenido, debes realizar `commit` seguido de `push`.

Con respecto a el directorio `.git` este solo se encuentra en tu  repositorio local no en el remoto. No debes eliminar este directorio ya que de otra forma no podràs realizar "confirmaciones" a el repositorio remoto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El directorio `.git` contiene toda la información necesaria para tu
> proyecto en control de versiones y toda la información sobre
> confirmaciones, dirección de repositorio remoto, etc. Todos ellos
> están presentes en esta carpeta. También contiene un registro que
> almacena su historial de confirmaciones para que pueda volver al
> historial.